Navola: Series or Standalone?
The question is in the title, and I ask because, having just finished it:

 I can't actually tell.  It ends in roughly the same position as Nine Princes In Amber with the protagonist having made good on an escape from prison, vowing revenge, and with other plot threads awaiting resolution-- most especially, the fate of his sister.  And yet, I can see no explicit indication anywhere in the book that a sequel is coming:  No mention that it is part of a series, no "to be continued", no blurb in the afterword, nothing that I saw on the author's web page.  Indeed, the full title of the book is "Navola: A Novel" which to me implies it is a complete entity.  A review in the Washington post thinks it's a series, but infers it from the ending.

So, can anyone confirm that is the first of a series?  Or a stand alone work?

According to the author, a sequel is intended.

AdamBomb: What a tale, an absolutely luscious tapestry of characters and setting! I couldn't put it down, especially the last 1/4 of the book. Desperately wanting the story to continue!
Paolo Bacigalupi: I promise there is more coming.

Note that it's a single line post on Blue-sky and I can't see any more detail.

I've edited to include the Q & A and give some more context. Try to avoid answers that depend on links, especially to social media that can be easily deleted.
